# Class 'AlternativeLaravelCache\Provider\AlternativeCacheStoresServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, asgardcms

I have the following class:

```php
namespace App\Providers;
 
use AlternativeLaravelCache\Provider\AlternativeCacheStoresServiceProvider;
 
/**
 * Note: Using 'dev-master' for the library. If *composer update* causes
 * issue, then refer to library's stable release version in composer.json
 * and update it.
 */
class CacheStoresServiceProvider extends AlternativeCacheStoresServiceProvider
{
    static protected $redisDriverName = 'redis'; // 'redis','altredis'
 
    static protected $fileDriverName = 'file'; // 'file','altfile'
 
    public function register()
    {
        if (env('CACHE_DRIVER') == 'array') {
            static::$fileDriverName = 'altfile';
        }
 
        parent::register();
    }
 
}
```

Using it caused the following error
Arguments

> Class 'AlternativeLaravelCache\Provider\AlternativeCacheStoresServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? Looks like auto-discovery doesn't work for your.

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve the error so far?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this in your config/app.php file

```
'providers' => [

    ...,
    \AlternativeLaravelCache\Provider\AlternativeCacheStoresServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).